# What are the differences and relations between type constructors and datatypes?

Tags: types, programming-languages, sml, ml

In Ullman's SML book,

- *9.3.2 Primitive Type Constructors* lists as type constructors: `ref`, `array`, and `vector`,
- *9.3.3 Primitive Datatypes* lists as datatypes: `bool`, `list`, `option`, and `order`.
- *6.1.1 Review of the ML Type System* lists as type constructors: `list`, `option`, `ref`, `array`, and `vector`.

Questions:

1. Are `lists` and `option`   datatypes,  type constructors, or both?
2. What are the differences and relations between type constructors and datatypes? I am confused by the following quotes:

   *Chapter 6 Defining Your Own Types*   says:

   > Datatype definitions are rules for constructing new types with new values that are not the values of previously defined types.

   *2.4 Tuples and Lists* says:

   > Most languages start with a similar collection of types and build more complex types with a set of operators called type constructors,
   >   which are dictions allowing us to define new types from simpler
   >   types.
3. If type constructors and datatypes can overlap, what is the opposite
   (mutual exclusive) concept to type constructor and what is the
   opposite (mutual exclusive) concept to datatype?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this answer is sensible.

1. `list` and `option` are both type constructors because they take a (prefix) type in order to construct a type. So `int list` is a type, but `list` itself is a type constructor. The same goes for `option` and `int option`, and so on.

   In Haskell and probably other type-oriented languages you would say that `int option` has kind `Type` while `option` has kind `Type -> Type`. Kinds are to types as types are to values, a means of saying things about all of them.

   So I believe that when you say "list is a type", this is loosely spoken. What you really mean is "`α list` is a type for any type `α`". And sometimes you specifically mean "`'a list` is a type" with `'a` being a type variable. The difference being that by α I mean some concrete type and by `'a` I mean some type variable.
2. When you create a data type, `datatype troolean = True | False | Derp`, then `troolean` is a type and `True`, etc., are (nullary) value constructors.

   When you create a data type, `datatype fiat = USD of int | ChildDrawing of png`, then `fiat` is a type and `Dollar` is a value constructor with type `int -> fiat`.

   When you create a data type, `datatype ('a, 'b) either = Left of 'a | Right of 'b`, then `('a, 'b) either` is a type, `either` is a type constructor (it takes two type parameters and constructs a type, but loosely spoken, "either is a type"), `Left` and `Right` are still value constructors.

   I'm not sure what confuses you about the quotes. Data types lets you create new types with new values that didn't exist (but the type most certainly is isomorphic to some type that existed). Composition of types is still possible, but even more powerful because you can compose types you made yourself for great precision and expressivity.

   I suppose you could call `troolean` a nullary type constructor, too, but it would probably be less confusing to say that `troolean`'s kind is `Type` and that `either`'s kind is... what?
3. > If type constructors and datatypes can overlap

   I'm not sure you can say that. Data types define new values. Sometimes those values have value parameters. Sometimes a data type itself has type parameters. When it does, its type constructor has a higher kind.